# How to check if user enters application via notification using Unity Mobile Notification package?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, mobile, notifications

I'm use [Unity Mobile Notification](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.3/manual/index.html) system for my game, but I have a little problem. How can I check if user eneters application via clicking notification?

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [Unity Mobile Notifications for Android](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.3/manual/Android.html). As long as you can attach some `Intent` data to your notification, you can always get this data inside `Activity`. Then if you get null from `getIntent()` you know you haven't get there from notification.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs you linked:

> If a user taps the notification to open the app, you can get the
> notification and retrieve any data assigned to it like in the example
> below.
>
> ```
> var notificationIntentData = AndroidNotificationCenter.GetLastNotificationIntent();
> if (notificationIntentData != null)
> {
>     var id = notificationIntentData.Id;
>     var channel = notificationIntentData.Channel;
>     var notification = notificationIntentData.Notification;
> }
> ```